# iOS - Check if user is already in the database

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I am trying to make a registration system for the iphone. Everything works fine and the server return the message after it checks if the user already exist. The only problem is that the alert view is not shown when  the string returned is equal to this one: [image]

This is the code:

PHP

```
//other stuff here 
//verify if user already in database

$verify = "SELECT userid 
                FROM user 
                WHERE userid=:user LIMIT 1;";


$verifyQry = $db_conn->prepare($verify);
$verifyQry->bindParam(':user', $user);
$verifyQry->execute();
$userExists = $verifyQry->fetch();


//if user not in the database, add!
if (!$userExists) {
$insert = 'INSERT INTO user(`userid`,`password`) VALUES (:user,:password)';
$qry = $db_conn->prepare($insert);
$qry->bindParam(':user', $user);
$qry->bindParam(':password', $pass);
$qry->execute();
$message = "success";

}else{
$message = "userExist"; 

}


echo utf8_encode($message);
```

XCODE

```
-(void)signUpWithUsername:(NSString *)username andWithPassword:(NSString *)password{

    //NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        //               objectForKey:@"tokenId"];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{



        NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username,
                            password];

        NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/api/registerUser.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

        NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);// I GOT THIS STRING FROM THE SERVER I


        if ([responseString  isEqualToString: @"userExist"]) {
            UIAlertView *userExistAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"User Exist" message:@"A user with this email address has already sign up. Did you forgot your password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"retrive password", nil];

            [userExistAlert show];
        }else{


        }


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Dismiss the viewController upon success


    });




}
```

Comment: [responseString  isEqualToString: @"userExist"] is going to return "NO" because the responseString has the date and other info before it.  You might want to try [responseString hasSuffix:@"userExist"] instead.

Comment: Have you tried isEqual: ?

Comment: I suspect that the "date and other info" are part of NSLog(). It does help if quotes (") are used in NSLog() to delineate the data. Something like: `NSLog(@"response from server: '@'", responseString);`

Comment: @Brice `isEqual` and `isEqualToString` work the same. `isEqualToString` is preferred here because strings are being compared.

Comment: Good point on the date/info Zaph.

Comment: @Brice yes I tried both

Comment: I know @Zaph, but I thought there might be something wrong with encoding while using isEqualToString:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the alertView was not shown but I was able to check if the string retuned from the server was equal to the "userExist". I fixed it using:

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

This is the code which now shows the alert view if the user already exist:

```
-(void)signUpWithUsername:(NSString *)username andWithPassword:(NSString *)password{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



        NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username,
                            password];

        NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/api/registerUser.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        responseString = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        NSLog(@"response string from server: '%@'", responseString);
        NSString *userExist = @"userExist";
        [userExist dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if ([responseString  isEqualToString: userExist]) {

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertView)
                                   withObject:responseString waitUntilDone:YES];


        }else{
            NSLog(@"User doesn't exist");

        }
    });
}


-(void)showAlertView{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"User exiat" message:@"user exist" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the data you receive from the server is not *exactly* why you think it is. It may have leading and/or trailing white space or new line characters.

To ensure there are no hidden surrounding characters use:

```
responseString = [responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];];
```

instead of:

```
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);// I GOT THIS STRING FROM THE SERVER I
```

use:

```
NSLog(@"response string from server: '@'", responseString);
```

I would also NSLog the `responseData` to insure that the encoding is what is expected and there are no hidden characters such as line feeds:

```
NSLog(@"response data from server: @", responseData);
```

Also Instead of:

```
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
```

use:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

When I have problems like this I use Charles Proxy to see exactly what the server is sending.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can that equalToString is working properly when I put NSLog(@"show alert") inside my if statement. The problem is related to the UIAlertView. The application doesn't crash but once I press the sign up button once then the button is not responding anymore. Can something related to dispatch_async?